# How ZSH interpret wildcards in a variable used by commands as a path

Tags: zsh, wildcards, path

I try to pass a variable with "*" (wildcard) via zsh script, but it doesn't work. ls, grep and other commands complaint about any path with "*".

This is simple example of a problem:

```
➜  ~ mkdir -p /tmp/TEST/{22,3}
➜  ~ ls -l /tmp/TEST/*
/tmp/TEST/22:

/tmp/TEST/3:
➜  ~ TEST_PATH="/tmp/TEST/*"
➜  ~ ls -l $TEST_PATH
ls: /tmp/TEST/*: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike other sh-like shells, zsh does not perform wildcard expansion and word splitting when expanding an unquoted variable. An unquoted `$TEST_PATH` is almost what you'd expect intuitively: a simple substitution of the value of the variable. “Almost” because if the result is an empty word, this word is removed altogether.

To take the value of a variable and expand wildcards in it, use the `${~…}` form of [parameter expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion): `${~TEST_PATH}` which can also be written without braces `$~TEST_PATH`.

If there are no matches, `$~TEST_PATH` triggers an error. To get an empty list instead, use the `N` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers): `$~TEST_PATH(N)`

Comment: Why does this not work on the RHS of an assignment? 
```f=*.txt; g=$~f``` still just assigns the unexpanded wildcard to `g`.

Comment: @MarkReed Both assignments are in a word context, so no wildcard expansion is done. You can run `f=*.txt; g=($~f)` to set `f` to a pattern and `g` to the list of file names resulting from expanding that pattern.